# I am trying to select the date from DateTime picker and I am getting an error

Tags: selenium, error-handling, automation

I am trying to select the date from DateTime picker and if I run one of the date picker code then it will run successfully, but when I run code for both of them, I am getting an error.

```
package testNgPackageTest;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;

public class InsightTalk {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    @Test  (priority = 0)

    public void insightTalk() {

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Insight Talks']")).click();
        System.out.println("click on insight talk menu");
        driver.navigate().refresh();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Add Insight Talk']")).click();
        System.out.println("click on insight talk create button");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='text'])[1]")).sendKeys("soupraTalk");
        System.out.println("click on insight talk name");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@class='md-textarea']")).sendKeys("soupramaitygrouptalje");
        System.out.println("click on insight talk  description");
        //start date time picker

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='text'])[2]")).click();
        System.out.println("click on insight talk start date time");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='vdatetime-calendar__navigation--next']")).click();
        System.out.println("click on next button ");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='vdatetime-calendar__month__day'])[16]")).click();
        System.out.println("click on insight talk start date ");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Ok']")).click();
        System.out.println("click on the ok button ");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='vdatetime-time-picker__item'])[3]")).click();
        System.out.println("click on the time button ");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Ok']")).click();
        System.out.println("click on the ok button ");

        //end date time picker

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='text'])[3]")).click();
        System.out.println("click on insight talk end date time");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='vdatetime-calendar__navigation--next']")).click();
        System.out.println("click on  next button ");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='vdatetime-calendar__month__day'])[16]")).click();
        System.out.println("click on insight talk end date ");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Ok']")).click();
        System.out.println("click on ok button ");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='vdatetime-time-picker__item'])[4]")).click();
        System.out.println("click on end time button ");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Ok']")).click();
        System.out.println("click on end ok button ");

    }
```

Error:

```
FAILED: insightTalk org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException:
Element <input id="" class="vdatetime-input" type="text"> is not
clickable at point (731,425) because another element <div
class="vdatetime-time-picker__item vdatetime-time-picker__item--selected">
obscures it
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the HTML as a code block.